# Convert UIColor initialization to Color Literal Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have multiple different UIColor objects. Some of them are initialized by a constructor some of them are shown as color literals.

```
static let optionsHeader = UIColor([ ]) // XCode is showing a color rect.
static let optionButtonSelected = UIColor(red: 0.865, green: 0.804, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

How can I convert the UIColor.init(...) statements to a color literal.

Comment: Post code as actual text in your question instead of as a picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RGB color literal is same as `UIColor` initialization:

```
#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

Or you can select color after typing `#colorLiteral()`.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use extensions to use hex color instead of inputting rgba values

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(hexString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        let hexString: String = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
        if (hexString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            scanner.scanLocation = 1
        }
        var color: UInt32 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt32(&color)
        let mask = 0x000000FF
        let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
        let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
        let b = Int(color) & mask
        let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let rgb:Int = (Int)(r*255)<<16 | (Int)(g*255)<<8 | (Int)(b*255)<<0
        return String(format:"#%06x", rgb)
    }

}
```

Then you can code it with:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#4A4A4A")
```

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question being asked.